# Substring in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, regex

How do I get the `access_token` value from this string?

**Input string**:

```
{\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":3600,\"access_token\":\"xb5Q4IFN4jWjRDxwFyjgWdBQpv4l\"}
```

**Desired output**:

```
"TQdcdvvPZTEtPMj7s8urQIg90y8g"
```

Is there a good reference for finding the solution?

Comment: I don't know how you get this string with all the extra escapes, but it looks like it comes from JSON. Consider using a JSON parser if that is the case.

Comment: What is the rule for identifying the token value?

Comment: your desired output for `access_token` is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily convert your string into a hash using `JSON.parse` method of [json gem](https://github.com/flori/json) and then just grab the `access_token` from the hash as following:

```
require 'json'
input_string = "{\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":3600,\"access_token\":\"xb5Q4IFN4jWjRDxwFyjgWdBQpv4l\"}"
JSON.parse(input_string)['access_token']
# => "xb5Q4IFN4jWjRDxwFyjgWdBQpv4l"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the last element of the array. So you could just remove the non-alphabetical characters.

```
array.last.gsub(/\W/,"");
```